# clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (3) passed to: client$batch

Tags: clojure, monitoring, riemann

I am new to closure and trying to setup [Riemann](http://riemann.io/quickstart.html) to monitor server resources and application events.  I have a Riemann server setup and am trying to add a Riemann client, which will forward events to the Riemann server.

This is my Riemann client configuration file:

```
; -*- mode: clojure; -*-
; vim: filetype=clojure

(logging/init :file "/var/log/riemann/riemann.log")

(require 'riemann.client)

; Listen on the local interface over TCP (5555), UDP (5555), and websockets (5556)
(let [host "0.0.0.0"]
  (tcp-server :host host)
  (udp-server :host host)
  (ws-server  :host host))

; Expire old events from the index.
(periodically-expire 10 {:keep-keys [:host, :service, :tags, :state, :description, :metric]})

(let [index (index)
      downstream (batch 100 1/10
        (async-queue! :agg { :queue-size 1e3
                             :core-pool-size 4
                             :max-pool-size 32}
      (forward
        (riemann.client/tcp-client :host "10.11.5.10"))))]

  (streams ; Inbound events will be passed to these streams:
    (default :ttl 60 ; Keep events in the index for 1 minute by default.
      index
      #(info %)
      (where (service #"^riemann.*") ; Send any events with service starting with riemann downstream
        downstream))))
```

Every time I try to start Riemann, I get the following exception printed to the logs:

```
ERROR [2016-05-17 14:58:58,118] main - riemann.bin - Couldn't start
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (3) passed to: client$batch
  at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:437)
  at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:47)
  at riemann.config$eval36.invoke(riemann.config:23)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
  at clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke(RT.java:318)
  at riemann.config$include.invoke(config.clj:285)
  at riemann.bin$_main.doInvoke(bin.clj:61)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
  at riemann.bin.main(Unknown Source)
```

I lifted this configuration file (almost verbatim) from pg. 93 of [The Art of Monitoring by James Turnbull](https://books.google.com/books?id=w5QfDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA83&dq=running%20riemann%20health&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q&f=false).  So I am confused what I could have done wrong.  Can someone help me to understand why this configuration file is throwing a wrong number of args error?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about forwarding events from one riemann server to another riemann server, right?

Comment: your code looks good, what version of riemann are you using?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt  

_Just to be clear, you are talking about forwarding events from one riemann server to another riemann server, right?_  

Yes, the other server is running riemann and bound to all interfaces (0.0.0.0)  

_your code looks good, what version of riemann are you using?_  

http://aphyr.com/riemann/riemann-0.2.4-1.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installed version of Riemann is ancient, you need 0.2.11+ to have a good time following that guide.

You can get the rpm at http://riemann.io

Answer (score 0):

I see you got your answer but it seems to me that the author of the book got some things about Clojure wrong on this one, and maybe that's not surprising because this is version v0.0.1 of the book.

The explanation for the code you've used says "Our binding defines a symbol called `downstream`. The value of this symbol is a series of streams. Our first stream is called `batch`." But it is clear from the code that `batch` is supposed to be the name of a function (or macro) that is called in the snippet.

Then it says "The batch stream passed the events into our `async-queue!` [...]" but the result of calling `async-queue!` is actually an argument with which `batch` is called.

Comment: rieman evaluates the functions listed in the example to produce other functions. These returned functions are referred to as streams throughout the documentation. In the paragraph you mention he is referring to the behaviour of the functions returned by running the code in the snippet. Which what the system will "do" when it's actually processing your events. That code spinet is correct and works. (provided you use the version of riemann that defines the `batch` function with 3-arity)